# Remote Control Program for ATMEGA168P circuit

Tags: led, atmega, remote-control

Hello I will make maybe a fool questions. I have this diagram:

[image: Diagram]

This diagram is to turn on/off led lights, make blink via remote control.
Now the questions are:

1.-What kind of remote control I can buy or what characteristics to buy for remote for this circuit? Link maybe?
2.-If depending of the remote control, how this circuit will know what brand I´m using, in other words how can I program the remote buttons to apply for each function on each pin of the ATMEGA like you see. Is this defined in the on the code you prgoramr into the ATMEGA?

Thank you

Comment: It might be worth adding a link to where the circuit came from, maybe it has source code and related information? It looks like it has a pair of infrared receivers but knowing what kind of remote controls it supports is impossible from the schematic alone, it will depend on the software loaded into the microcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some popular IR codec code for AVR/Arduino:
http://www.righto.com/2009/08/multi-protocol-infrared-remote-library.html
https://github.com/shirriff/Arduino-IRremote

You will need to choose a remote-control, and then program the AVR to do whatever it is you want the car lights to do when you push various remote buttons.

Comment: The link from where is posted that is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8p1LnwWfDqU

Comment: This what you mention apply for that video? There is the source code and all or is needed to do something more?

Comment: I mean in that source code what kind of remote control is using to buy?

Comment: Ok, so all the code you need in the 168 is already done for you: https://yoctfs.jp/res/box-l-k5qpinvayh7rdwb4m4y3aggdf4-1001?account=storage&expires=1433540067&uid=7ebf08fd-59a0-46ae-aa7b-e599d7aa6b0c&signature=ZTgzMTExM2QxMzU5ZjQ0Mjk1OTk1ZTMyNjg1MmJkZGNiY2E1ZjlmMw--

Comment: And for a remote control, I suspect any Sony TV remote will work.